# Why PHP has separate version of ts(thread safe)/nts(non thread safe) while it doesn't support multi-threading?

Tags: php, thread-safety

I think the title is clear.

Comment: I think it would still be polite to phrase the question body properly.

Comment: I recall reading something along the lines of: `IIS=NTS` & `Apache=TS`.

Comment: @jnpcl It's usually the other way around. But in Apache case it really depends on the Apache MPM in use. Apache on Windows for instance can only use threads.

Comment: PHP has supported multi-threading for a very long time - but the PHP developers sensibly flagged up that they don't know which third party extensions (a large number of which come bundled with PHP) are thread-safe

Answer (score 24):

While you can't spawn threads from PHP code you can use PHP with a multi-threaded web server that handles concurrent requests on different threads. In this case the TS (thread-safe) version of PHP should be used.

The TS version of PHP keeps the state of each request in its own memory location. This is necessary because all requests in a multi-threaded server share the same address space.

The alternative is to use a multi-process (usually prefork) server. With such a server some state can be kept in global variables without affecting concurrent requests. That's how the NTS (non thread-safe) version of PHP is implemented.

Comment: Why don't they just use thread-safe all the time? Does non-thread-safe have any benefits?