# php-apc for windows xampp

Tags: php, windows, xampp, apc

I need to install php-apc library on windows just to be able to keep developing my app on windows as well.

I went to http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ and downloaded `php_apc-3.1.10-5.3-vc9-x86.zip` . The problem is know that inside the zip file, there are 2 folders that contain the php apc library, `nts` and `ts` folders!

From which should I copy the library to my `c:\xampp\php\ext` folder? What is the difference?

Comment: The URL is no more. For windows use http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc/sorting/1.html.

Comment: This link may be more permanent: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apc/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Run `phpinfo()` and check `Zend Extension Build`. In my case it's API220090626,NTS,VC9, so it's `nts`. The difference between `ts` and `nts` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983904/why-php-has-separate-version-of-tsthread-safe-ntsnon-thread-safe-while-it-do)

Answer (score 13):

Look in phpinfo() for `Thread Safety` key :

IF `Thread Safety`==`enabled` -> copy from TS folder

IF `Thread Safety`==`disabled` -> copy from NTS folder

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

It's just about Thread safe and Non thread safe.

Check your installation with phpinfo() in the section Thread Safety. If it says enabled go for TS folder, else NTS.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to know similar questions about ts (thread Safe) or nts (Not Thread Safe) which VC and whether x86 or x64.

The best place for this information is in your XAMPP folder. Open the file XAMPP/readme_en.txt

At the top of this file you will find the versions, and specifications, of each component of XAMPP.

```
Important! PHP in this package needs the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008     Redistributable package from
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582. Please     ensure that the VC++ 2008 runtime
libraries are installed on your system.    

+ Apache 2.4.4
+ MySQL 5.5.32 (Community Server)
+ PHP 5.6.3 (VC11 X86 32bit thread safe) + PEAR `     + PHP 5.4.25 (VC9 X86 32bit [b]thread safe[/b]) + PEAR
...
```

The important line is:

```
+ PHP 5.6.3 (VC11 X86 32bit thread safe) + PEAR
```

This line is telling me the following:

```
PHP version = 5.6.3
vc# code = VC11 = vc11
os bit sise = X86 32bit = x86
threading model = thread safe = ts
```

I was actually looking for memcache and found it here:

```
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/
```

With the above info I selected:

```
php_memcache-3.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip
```

This breaks down as:

```
version of Memcahe: php_memcache-3.0.8-
version of php: 5.6-
thread safe: ts-
MS VC Version: vc11-
For 32 bit x86: x86.zip
```